# Standard ASP.Net Core tag helpers aren't purple and bold

Tags: razor, razor-pages, tag-helpers

I have this cshtml, and it doesn't highlight Asp.Net Core tag helpers, like `<form>`, `<input>`, `<span>`, `<textarea>`. I was partially able to workaround this issue by using @Html.DisplayFor, and it worked. But otherwise I have no idea what's wrong with that. My Visual Studio version is 2017 15.8.2, and the same tag helpers ARE purple and bold in another project.

Here's some code (cshtml):

```
<form method="post">
    <div asp-validation-summary="All" class="text-danger"></div>
    <table>
        <tr>
        <td>@Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.NoteModel.NoteName)</td>
        <td><input asp-for="NoteModel.NoteName" class="form-control" data-val-required="The NoteName field is required." data-val-maxlength-max="15" data-val="true" /></td>
        <td><span asp-validation-for="NoteModel.NoteName" class="text-danger"></span></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
        <td>@Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.NoteModel.TranslatedNoteName)</td>
        <td><input asp-for="NoteModel.TranslatedNoteName" class="form-control" data-val-required="The TranslatedNoteName field is required." data-val-maxlength-max="100" data-val="true" /></td>
        <td><span asp-validation-for="NoteModel.TranslatedNoteName" class="text-danger"></span></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
        <td>@Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.NoteModel.NoteText)</td>
        <td><textarea asp-for="NoteModel.NoteText"
                  class="form-control" data-val-required="The NoteText field is required." 
                  data-val-maxlength-max="8000" data-val="true" 
                  data-val-maxlength="The field NoteText must be a string or array type with a maximum length of '8000'."
                  rows="20" cols="100"></textarea></td>
        <td><span asp-validation-for="NoteModel.NoteText" class="text-danger"></span></td>
        </tr>
    </table>

    <div>
        Upload an image: <input type="file" name="image" accept=".jpg" />
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Upload</button>
    </div>
</form>
```

There're data annotations in the NoteModel class, and @Html.DisplayFor renders them properly.

Any ideas? Thanks in advance.

**UPDATE:**

Tags are not rendered properly into HTML, all the attributes `asp-` stay in HTML. Apparently, I'm doing some silly mistake, which I'm not able to figure out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tag helpers are an opt-in feature. They are not available to the page by default. They are enabled by adding an `@addTagHelper` directive to the page, or more usually to a *_ViewImports.cshtml* file:

```
@addTagHelper *, Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.TagHelpers
```

Check to see if the taghelpers are enabled.

Ref: https://www.learnrazorpages.com/razor-pages/tag-helpers/

Comment: Yes, custom tag helpers are highlighted if @addTagHelper presents, and it works in my project. However, I was asking about built-in Asp.Net Core tags, that it uses for marking up programming elements, like <form>, <input>, etc. They ALSO should be highlighted by Visual Studio, and it works in another project. I suspect that my project (which initially was created as MVC) does not properly work as Razor Pages project. I will try to create a new Razor Pages project from scratch, and transfer my code there, and see what's gonna happen.

Comment: It actually worked! Thanks for helping me. Strange that in the other project this @addTagHelper was not necessary/

Comment: Sometimes I have to remove `@addTagHelper *, Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.TagHelpers ` from  _ViewImports.cshtml_, build, addTagHelper again to _ViewImports,  unload the project, then reload again. Then I get the syntax highlight/bold for asp- tags.

Answer (score 1):

I am working through the RazorPagesMovie tutorial and all the bold disappeared from my taghelpers. Very annoying.  I had to close down VS 2019 and restart and open back up the project. It is working.  For the time being anyway.